Ubuntu : Clone a git project in VS code. remote: HTTP Basic: Access denied. Authentication failed
I am using Linux - Ubuntu 64.
I want to clone a gitlab project to my local machine in VS code.
I did below commands:

Went to gitlab repo. Clicked 'Clone' with HTTPS.
It opens VS code. I entered my username and password.
Got Authentication failed error.
I even tried entering my access token instead of password. Still same error.



i tried the personal access token as told. When I tried the SSH, I got error: Permission denied (Public Key).
